# LinkedList Deep copy java

Tags: java, linked-list, clone

I was trying to do the deep copy of my linked list known as `DictionaryNode` which I did but i was not able to display it's content in display method as it is always null. why DictinaryNode temp is always null ? and if i try to assign temp = head work but with temp = copy doesn't.

```
public class ListOfNodes {

public class DictionaryNode {
    protected String word;
    private int level;
    private DictionaryNode next;
    private int space = 0;

    public void displayCopy() {
        DictionaryNode temp = copy.next;
        while( temp != null ) {
            System.out.println(temp.word)
                temp = temp.next;
        }
    }


    public DictionaryNode( String word, int level ) {
        this.word = word;
        this.level = level;
        next = null;
    }
}

private DictionaryNode head = null;
public DictionaryNode copy  = null;

//used to do deep copy
public void Clone() {
    DictionaryNode temp =  head.next;

    while( temp != null ) {
        copy = new DictionaryNode( temp.word , temp.level );
        copy  = copy.next;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}

public void displayCopy() {
    DictionaryNode temp = copy.next;
    while( temp != null ) {
        Sytem.out.println(temp.word)
            temp = temp.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never assign a value to `head`.  Also, I think your clone method should return a reference to the cloned dictionary.

Comment: head is initialized via user reading from file but problem is if I try to assign temp reference of head it works and display me all the content but if I try temp = copy doesn't work

Comment: If so, then the code you posted isn't what you're actually running.

Answer (score 1):

This program will demonstrate how to do a deep copy on a list. It's more generic than your specific example so hopefully it helps others too.

```
public class Java_Practice {

private static class LinkedListTest {

    private String data;
    private LinkedListTest next;

    public LinkedListTest(String data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public LinkedListTest getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(LinkedListTest next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LinkedListTest [data=" + data + ", next=" + next + "]";
    }

}

// Do a deep copy
private static LinkedListTest copyLlt(LinkedListTest original) {

    LinkedListTest copy = new LinkedListTest(original.getData() + " copied");

    LinkedListTest nextCopy = original.getNext();
    LinkedListTest current = copy;

    while (nextCopy != null) {

        LinkedListTest newCopy = new LinkedListTest(nextCopy.getData() + " copied");
        newCopy.setNext(nextCopy.getNext());

        current.setNext(newCopy);

        current = newCopy;
        nextCopy = newCopy.getNext();
    }

    return copy;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedListTest firstLlt = new LinkedListTest("First");
    LinkedListTest secondLlt = new LinkedListTest("Second");
    LinkedListTest thirdLlt = new LinkedListTest("Thrid");

    firstLlt.setNext(secondLlt);
    secondLlt.setNext(thirdLlt);

    LinkedListTest copiedLlt = copyLlt(firstLlt);

    // Data should say First, Second, Third
    System.out.println("Original LinkedListTest: " + firstLlt.toString());

    // Data should say First Copied, Second Copied, Third Copied
    System.out.println("Copied LinkedListTest: " + copiedLlt.toString());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Clone` method you never assign a `next` field for the copied content. You need to do this to have more than a single connected node in the copy. Furthermore you need to copy the head too. Moreover do must not overwrite `copy` with anything but the copy of the head:

```
copy = new DictionaryNode(null, head.level);
DictionaryNode temp =  head.next;
DictionaryNode current = copy;

while( temp != null) {
    DictionaryNode nn = new DictionaryNode( temp.word , temp.level);
    current.next = nn;
    current = nn;
    temp = temp.next;
}
```

Comment: but copy = new DictionaryNode(null, head.level);  why null instead word ?

Comment: @Anny: Isn't the head just a element before the first element? I do not know the details of your list. If this is not the element before the first element but the first element itself, take care to avoid a `NullPointerException`. (and use `head.word` instead of `null`)